Why did the 1st person plural present ending change from -em (in Proto-West-Germanic) to -en (in German)?
I am interested, in Proto-West-Germanic, the 1st person plural present ending was -em. Why did it change to -en on the path to German? And why didn't the same sound change merge the articles "dem" and "den"?

One of the things you should accept when interested in languages is, that "why"-questions don't fit very well to that topic. Most of the developments of a language are unconscious decisions made by the majority of the language users - even they couldn't answer "why".

Even if such a sound change happens in present time, it would be hard to explain for the speakers themselves why the way they are speaking changes. As for why dem did not change, one obvious reason is that it's a single word so the syllable is stressed, whereas endings are usually unstressed and therefore more prone to sound changes.

What exactly are you asking for? Ending of what? Since you mention person (1st person) and number I guess that you mean verbs. But what do verb and articles have in common? Why should they undergo the same changes?

@HubertSchölnast I would expect the verb endings to undergo the same sound changes as the endings of the articles because that's how sound changes work. Sound changes don't care whether a word is a verb or an article.

You have to acknowledge that this does not have the typical properties of a  sound shift. In a sound shift, the language's phonemes are affected, like merging phonemes, creating new allophones or splitting these allophones into multiple phonemes. Nothing of the sort happened here. German still had /m/ and /n/ as different phonemes. It just replaced some final "-m"s with final "-n" where possible, and the speakers would have been at all times able to differentiate between "-m" and "-n" if needed.
We can only speculate why some forms are replaced, and why some aren't.
In all Germanic languages the marking of person in the plural reduced drastically, with most languages having only one plural form. In fact, many German dialects also have just one plural form. Keeping the plural endings apart just does not seem to be a big priority.
In contrast, dem and den or einem and einen for a more similar environment make a very important contrast, that of dative and accusative, so a clear distinction between m and n was needed. But for adjectives following articles? There, it's not so important anymore, and we only have "-n", while Old High German still had some forms with m, like blintōm for dative plural.
To add another case where "-m" became "-n", there is the dative plural, where already in Old High German, we had both forms with "n" and "m", see this declination table.. Here again, there was no need to differentiate these forms.
As for all "why" questions to language change, we can only list possible reasons, but we can never know for sure what exactly caused it.
